# Making the most of my factory

Tags: angularjs, http, service, resources, factory

I am new to Angular, so if you ask the question: "Why don't you...?" The answer is...because I didn't know I could.

Have a factory make an API call, then inject that factory into a parent controller that will have scope over the entire page. Then have child controllers nested and inherit from the parent controller.

Here is what I have so far. I may be WAY off here, and if that is the case, please tell me. I am working on this alone, and have no help, so any help is welcomed.

Thank you.

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
app.factory('myFactory', function($http){
    var MyFactory = function(){};

    MyFactory.getParams = function(){
        return $http.get('/getparameters');
        .success(function(data){
            var roomname = data.roomname;
        })
        MyFactory.getRoom(roomname);
    };

    MyFactory.getRoom = function(room){
        return $http.get('/my/api/' + room);
    };


});

app.controller('RoomCtrl', function($scope, myFactory){
    $scope.data = myFactory;        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use resource, you need use promise;
**EDITED**
I tried to make more clear for you

```
app.factory('apicall', ['$q','$http',function($q, $http){

    function getRoom(options){
      var promise =  $http.get(options.paramUrl)
                    .success(function(data){
                         //handle your error
                         return $http.get(options.roomUrl + data.roomname);              
                     })
                     .error(function(msg){
                          return $q.when(msg)
                      })   
           return promise;
    }

   return {getRoom:getRoom};
 }])
```

if you want call your factory in where you want

```
app.controller('RoomCtrl', ['$scope','apicall',function($scope, apicall){
       var options = {
                        paramUrl:'/getparameters',
                        roomUrl:'/my/api/'
                     }
       apicall.getRoom.all(function(result){
            $scope.data = result; 
        })

  }]);
```

Comment: And the second part of this answer, the apicall.get.all(function(result){}) goes in a controller?

Comment: Because what I am trying to do is have a factory that is injected into a parent controller, and then have child controllers inherit from the parent.

Comment: Yes you should inject your factory into controller, directive or service which you want. Also, please note that extending controllers from each other is worse for angular stracture. Because, controllers should be unique. It may cause repeated transactions. Instead of inheriting controllers, use services, providers or factories. However don't use parent, child controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually separate different API calls in different factories that return a `$resource`.

For example, let's say we have 2 different API calls that point to different resources:

**yourwebsite.com/user/:userId** - returns data about the user

**yourwebsite.com/photo/:photoId** - return data about some photo

In angular, you would split these in 2 different factories:
"use strict";

```
angular.module("App.services").
factory("User",["$resource", function($resource){
    return $resource("yourwebsite.com/user/:userId"),{userId:"@userId"});
}]);
```

and second

```
angular.module("App.services").
factory("Photo",["$resource", function($resource){
    return $resource("yourwebsite.com/photo/:photoId"),{photoId:"@photoId"});
}]);
```

In your controller, you would use them like so:

```
angular.module("App.controllers").controller("TestController",["User","Photo", function(User, Photo){
    User.get({
        id:10
    }).$promise.then(function(data){
            console.log(data); //returns the data for user with the id=10
        });

    Photo.get({
            id:123
    }).$promise.then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
    });

}]);
```

Usually `$resource` maps a [CRUD API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)(what I posted above is a basic example of a GET call).Check out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) on `$resource` - It already has the basic `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` functions.

I would recommend using `$http` if you have only 1 simple operation on that URL and not all 4 of them. You can then inject `$http` in your controller and do the request there instead of creating a factory for it.

If you have 2 requests and they are chained(second one depends on the data received from the first one) you have to wait until the first one is resolved. With `$resource` you can do this in the following way:

```
angular.module("App.controllers").controller("TestController",["User","Photo", function(User, Photo){
        var user_promise = User.get({
            id:10
        }).$promise.then(function(data){
                console.log(data); //returns the data for user with the id=10
                return data;

            });

        var photo_promise = Photo.get({
                id:123
        }).$promise.then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    return data;
        });

     user_promise.then(photo_promise).
      catch(function(error){
        console.log(error); //catch all errors from the whole promise chain
     });

    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The $q service helps you to handle combination of two asynchronous calls

```
app.factory('apicall', function($q, $http) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get('/getparameters')
    .success(
      function(data) {
        var roomname = data.roomname;
        $http.get(baseURL + 'room/' + roomname)
          .success(
            function(roomData) {
              deferred.resolve(roomData);
            }
        )
          .error(
            function() {
              deferred.reject();
            }
        )
      })
    .error(
      function() {
        deferred.reject();
      }
  );

  return deferred.promise;
});
```

And here is controller where you can use your service

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function(apicall) {
  apicall.then(
    function(roomData) {
      //success
    },
    function() {
      //error
    }
  )
})
```